# Creating child frames of main frame in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying create a new frame in wxPython that is a child of the main frame so that when the main frame is closed, the child frame will also be closed.

Here is a simplified example of the problem that I am having:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import wx

class App(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
       frame = MainFrame()
       frame.Show()
       self.SetTopWindow(frame)
       return True

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    title = "Main Frame"

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, 1, self.title) #id = 5

        menuFile = wx.Menu()

        menuAbout = wx.Menu()
        menuAbout.Append(2, "&About...", "About this program")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(menuAbout, "&Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, id=2)

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        AboutFrame().Show()

class AboutFrame(wx.Frame):

    title = "About this program"

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, 1, -1, self.title) #trying to set parent=1 (id of MainFrame())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

If I set AboutFrame's parent frame to None (on line 48) then the About frame is succesfully created and displayed but it stays open when the main frame is closed.

Is this the approach that I should be taking to create child frames of the main frame or should I be doing it differently, eg. using the onClose event of the main frame to close any child frames (this way sounds very 'hackish').

If I am taking the correct approach, why is it not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class AboutFrame(wx.Frame):

    title = "About this program"

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, wx.GetApp().TopWindow, title=self.title)
```

Comment: I think instead of passing wx.GetApp().TopWindow inside __init__. It should be passed OnAbout method